# Can you have deferred services with emberjs?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am trying to load data using Ember CLI from a legacy API that seems to be unsuited to using Ember Data. This data will typically be loaded when the page loads and then reused in many places throughout the app. I have created a service 'legacy_data' for this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  ready: null,
  legacy_data: null,

  init(){
   this.ready = Ember.$.ajax( ... ).done(function(legacy_data){
     this.set('legacy_data', legacy_data);
  }

  computed_attr: Ember.computed('legacy_data', function(){ ... },

  ...more functions and computed attributes
});
```

Because 'init' function does not seem to support returning a promise (Like the model hook on a route does), whenever I want to use this service, I have to do something like this:

```
injected_service.ready.then(function(legacy_data){
 ... use service
});
```

Which in practice means I end up with a whole bunch of additional promise handling in my codebase - It feels like I am swimming against the current on this one.

Is there a better way of doing this? Perhaps a lifecycle hook or a factory/initializer that supports deferred service initialization, so that I do not then have to worry about it everywhere else in my codebase? Do initializers support this? I have not seen it in any examples of it. Is there an alternative way of working around this issue? (Ember data must handle this same issue somehow, but I am new to the framework so am unsure)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ember, Route's have hook such as `beforeModel`, `model`, `afterModel`. If you return promises from these hooks, promise handling are done by Ember.

By the way, even if you are using Ember Data, calling `store` should be done by routes. If you access the store in your components, again you need to handle promises.

But, you are asking a way to defer the application till the promise resolved. This can be achieved by `application route`s `beforeModel` hook. (I've needed this to retrieve the user permissions in my client app. Since I cannot place the permission promise handling in my all routes, I put it in my `application route`.) So, have a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/09432acf4a0cd7b1ae17568d70ad73ff?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just move your code from the `init` hook to a function `loadData` (or whatever name you like), and then call this function from the `beforeModel` of the application route. This will ensure the data is loaded all the time.